# Resizing xib to be used for UITableView's section header view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I'm trying to use a xib-based UIView for my UITableView's section header views.

My xib's size is set to "freeform" and it's 600px wide. The width should be fluid though, and adapt to the tableView's width. Instead, I'm getting a 600px wide view rendering, making it look off-centered.

I'm using auto layout, but since I'm using a separate xib, I can't figure out where to set the constraints so that the section view's width matches it's tableview's.

The red part is my section header, and I'm showing the full width of the phone.
[image]

Comment: Have you implemented referenceSizeForHeaderInSection in your collectionViewLayout?

Comment: I'm using a UITableView, not UICollectionView

Comment: post the method body of viewForHeaderInSection in that case

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I originally tried two different approaches:

- Added a view to my storyboard, set the view to the same class as my xib, created an outlet, and inside `viewForHeaderInSection` I just returned `self.sectionHeaderView`
- Didn't add anything to storyboard, but instead, inside `viewForHeaderInSection`, I just instantiated a new class and returned `sectionHeaderView`.

Using both approaches I was able to have the xib render, but not adjust it's width.

To get this working, in viewDidLoad, I registered my xib with my tableView:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"HeaderView" bundle:nil] forHeaderFo`oterViewReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView"];
```

Then, in `viewForHeaderInSection`, I did:

```
HeaderView *headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"HeaderView"];
return headerView;
```

Having registered my xib with my tableView ahead of time, the tableView was able to resize it's section header view.